Incoming request was not authorized to invoke google cloud function
I have a firebase function deployed with the following Permissions
Cloud Functions Invoker - allUsers
In the function itself, I ensure that the incoming request is signed with the token as follows
import { auth } from "firebase-admin";

// ...
const token = request.headers.authorization?.split("Bearer ")[1];
const decodedToken = await auth().verifyIdToken(token);
const uid = decodedToken.uid;

This token is sent from a mobile app written in React native as follows
const currentUser = auth().currentUser;

const response = await axios.post(
  "URL TO FUNCTION",
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await currentUser?.getIdToken()}`,
    },
  }
);


The JWT is generated correctly and I've verified it with jwt.io. However, I'm unable to invoke the function with the following error in the Cloud functions logs:

The request was not authorized to invoke this service.


Please edit the question to show the complete minimal code that anyone can use to duplicate the behavior (not just a few lines out of context).

Can you share details asked in the above comment?
